# ArcScene for indoor-navigation?

Tags: arcscene

I'm new to the field of gis but I was wondering if there exists anything in ArcScene for indoor-navigation. I have to model a building and then implement a wayfinding component for it. Does ArcScene provide this feature for me or should I think about switching to another tool?

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. I'm not sure about this use of ArcScene (but I'm sure there are others who are), but it might help us to understand your needs if you can explain what data you have, and the details of your wayfinding (indoor route planning?) component. You can just edit (click edit above) your question to add these details, or anything else you can think of that might help.

Answer (score 1):

See the [Campus examples and templates](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/localgovernment/10.2/index.html#/What_is_Campus_Editing/028s00000002000000/) for ArcGIS for modeling indoor space and navigation